# Hide folder from set of files in tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a few different types of files:

`*.ts
*.client.ts
*.server.ts`

and my project is setup like:

`Project/
    src/
        A/
        B/`

I would like to:
- hide all of `src/A/**/*` from my `src/**/*.client.ts` files
- hide all of `src/B/**/*` from my `src/**/*.server.ts` files.

By "hide" I mean "cannot be imported".

Is this possible using some configuration of tsconfig.json files?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this "cannot be imported" policy? What is the reasoning behind this restriction?

Comment: My code runs on an unusual environment. `*.ts` and `*.client.ts` run on one machine, `*.ts` and `*.server.ts` run on a different machine. Files in folder `A/` are "server only" and files in folder `B/` are "client only". However, any other `*.ts` file is shared between the two.

Comment: So the accidentally imported file will simply not be found at runtime?

Comment: Yep, exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By "hide" I mean "cannot be imported".

You can *always* import a file that is not specified in the `tsconfig.json`. TypeScript will automatically *add* such imports into the compilation context.

## Reason

Examples of various file organizations e.g. this is how `node_modules/**/*.d.ts` files get included in the compilation context.